# Stop Auto Restarting Program

Tags: windows-10

I am working on Windows 10 64 bit and I have a program that keeps restarting. I would uninstall it, but it would pop back after some time. When its running, it sort of disables login to online games.

The program is named `a2e791e7385083db6933396a66bba56e.exe`, and it has a folder in `C:\program files`, called `ca8988ba68ec727745de2d83a76fb555`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Seems like a `virus` or `Trojan`.

Comment: I would suggest updating your antivirus and run full system scan. If it does not resolve the issue,you can use [autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) to remove it manually.

Comment: See if you can delete the folder in program files.

Comment: boot from a LiveCD of a AV product and do a full virus scan or use Windows Defender offline scan (in defender settings)

Answer (score 0):

That does not appear to be a valid program.  It could easily be a `virus` I would suggest:

- delete it if you can
- boot into safe mode and delete that file if you can't while in normal boot
- update your antivirus and run a full system scan
- examine your event viewer, perhaps you can see what program is causing this?
- is there a scheduled task that puts this back on? look at your windows scheduler for anything strange
- if all else fails, I would suggest combo fix: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/combofix/

Comment: Well i can delete it. It just pops back up.